# How to submit HTML label using a URL parameter?

Tags: html, url, url-parameters

I have the following code:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php yourls_e( 'shorten!!!!! ヾ(≧▽≦*)o', 'isq_translation'); ?>">
```

(dont mind the php it is just for translation)
I want to be able to submit this input through a URL parameter. Example: `https://example.com/?submit=true` or something like that. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Give the input a `name`. It can't be a successful control without one.

Comment: Thank you! But is that the way to do it?

Comment: Why would I post an answer saying to do that if it wasn't?

Comment: Ah. Got it. Thank you!